# Change conditionally a variable value for different feeds

Tags: feed

I need to change conditionally a variable value for different feeds. I can't find a function for this. These are my custom feeds:

```
function my_custom_rss_init(){
    add_feed('fc_md', 'my_custom_rss');
    add_feed('fc_ro', 'my_custom_rss');
    add_feed('fc_ua', 'my_custom_rss');
}
```

And I need something like this:

```
if( is_feed_name_fun( 'fc_md' ) ) $country = 'MD';
if( is_feed_name_fun( 'fc_ro' ) ) $country = 'RO';
if( is_feed_name_fun( 'fc_ua' ) ) $country = 'UA';
```

Is this possible? How can I accomplish it?

**UPDATE**

The last three code lines will be in a feed template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feed name will be stored in the query var `feed`-

```
$feed_name = get_query_var('feed');
if( 'fc_md' == $feed_name ) $country == 'MD';
```